# rosjava actionclient and roscpp actionserver

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I can send msg from rosjava based actionclient to roscpp based actionserve. I have found that only first time waitForResult() in actionclient works:
finished_before_timeout = sac.waitForResult(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

If I code sends goals many times then server gets the msga but client does not wait after first time at the above statement. Has someone else faced the same problem. Is there any solution how to send a goal again and wait for that in rosjava client?
I get follwing excepiton:
java.lang.NullPointerException
at plannerC.main_planner(Unknown Source)
at plannerC.onStart(Unknown Source)
at org.ros.internal.node.DefaultNode$1.run(DefaultNode.java:495)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

Thanks and regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33097/rosjava-actionclient-and-roscpp-actionserver/) by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2012-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

actionlib isn't yet supported with the latest release of rosjava. I will remove it from the repository for clarity.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1